# Create a Python list filled with the same string over and over and a number that increases based on a variable.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a list that is populated by a reoccurring string and a number that marks which one in a row it is. The number that marks how many strings there will be is gotten from an int variable.

So something like this:

```
b = 5
a = range(2, b + 1)
c = []
c.append('Adi_' + str(a))
```

I was hoping this would create a list like this:

```
c = ['Adi_2', 'Adi_3', 'Adi_4', 'Adi_5']
```

Instead I get a list like this

```
c = ['Adi_[2, 3, 4, 5]']
```

So when I try to print it in new rows

```
for x in c:
    print"Welcome {0}".format(x)
```

The result of this is:

```
Welcome Adi_[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The result I want is:

```
Welcome Adi_2
Welcome Adi_3
Welcome Adi_4
Welcome Adi_5
```

If anybody has Ideas I would appreciate it.

Comment: You already have the string formatted.  You should change the print line to "Welcome Adi_" and format the number directly into the string.  You dont have to worry about modifying elements inside of a list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
for i in a:
    c.append('Adi_' + str(i))
```

Your initial line was transforming the *whole* list `a` as a string.

Note that you could get rid of the loop with a list comprehension and some [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
c = ['Adi_%s' % s for s in a]
```

or

```
c = ['Adi_{0}'.format(s) for s in a] #Python >= 2.6
```

Comment: Yeah this did it for me. Now I understand the list formating but I don't understand the s. I'm gonna go google list substitutions :D. Thank youuu.

Comment: @Adilicious Check http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings and http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 1):

Or as a list comprehension:

```
b = 5
a = range(2, b + 1)
c = ["Adi_" + str(i) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehensions:

```
b = 5
a = range(2, b + 1)
c = ['Adi_'+str(i) for i in a]
for x in c:
    print"Welcome {0}".format(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or all on one line:

```
>>> for s in ['Welcome Adi_%d' % i for i in range(2,6)]:
...     print s
... 
Welcome Adi_2
Welcome Adi_3
Welcome Adi_4
Welcome Adi_5
```